How to fix a simple error in Atmel studio
I am programming an Atmega chip using Atmel studio 7. I try to define F_CPU on the first line of the main.c file. This F_CPU definition is used inside the other files. However when I compile the program the F_CPU symbol definition can't be seen by other files and the compiler throws the error shown in the picture.
Thanks
The picture showing the error...
[]

The duplicate does not answer what to do if you use this IDE. OP does not have access to the command line directly.

@0___________, there's no particular reason why the issue needs to be solved by using a feature of the IDE.  In fact, it would be better to use standard C features to solve it.  In particular, the definition should be put in a header file, which is then #included in other files that want access to the definition.  This is a variation on a frequently asked question.  Nothing in the question -- nor in your answer -- suggests any distinction from the multiple others on the same topic.

@JohnBollinger no it is not the right way as you will have to modify standard Atmel supplied header files as they use this definition. It is the only correct way of doing it when you use this framework.

If that's the case, @0___________, then you should edit the question to express that detail.  "This F_CPU definition is used inside the other files" does not clearly express that the definition is used by system headers, and that's critical for your answer to make sense as a preferred approach.

Your #define is only visible in the main.c file. It is not defined in any other source files in your project.
What you should do:
define F_CPU in the project properties.
Right click project > Properties > Toolchain > AVR/GNU C++ Compiler > Symbols
Configuration: All Configurations
Under "Defined symbols", add F_CPU=8000000UL

from now on your F_CPU will be visible be all files in your project.
EDIT
It is the preferable way of defining this macrodefinition as it is used by Atmel supplied header and source files.
